# Iterator to a specific character in a std::string

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I need an iterator to a specific character in a `std::string`, without looping from the beginning.

Is this the best way to do it?

```
std::string s("abcdefg...");
size_t id = 5;
std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
std::advance(it, id - 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also simply do:

```
std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin() + (id-1);
```

although it should have more or less the same performance of `std::advance`, since, if `it` is a random access iterator, `advance` uses `operator+` (otherwise it resorts to looping; this happens e.g. for `list` iterators).

Comment: I forgot std::string allocation is contiguous... Grazie!

Comment: @PietroM: it has nothing to do with whether `string` allocation is contiguous, it has to do with the iterator type. `deque` doesn't have contiguous allocation, but it does have random-access iterators, and so its iterators have `operator+`.

Comment: @PietroM: prego, ma effettivamente è come dice Steve Jessop. :) The fact that strings guarantee contiguous memory allocation, instead, allows you to move inside the string using pointers (obtained e.g. with `&(s[0])`) .

Answer (score 4):

Since `std::string`'s iterators are random access, you can directly do this:

```
std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin() + (id-1);
```

(This is what `std::advance` eventually expands to for random access iterators.)